# python aiogram3 проблема если бота использует сразу несколько пользователей

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram-3.x

Искал по интернету, не смог найти ответ, поэтому спрашиваю здесь.
У меня есть тг бот который проверяет твои знания английского:
ты нажимаешь на кнопку Отправить английское слово, он отправляет тебе английское слово, на которое ты должен написать перевод, если перевод верный то бот отправляет что все хорошо, если нет, то отправляет что неправильно и отправляет правильный перевод. Я все сделал у меня все получилось, решил протестить и скинул своим одноклассникам, но выяснилось что бот работает некорректно:
он отправляет пользователям не тот перевод. Посидев подумав я решил закреплять на каждым пользователем перевод, и сверяться по нему, т.е. создаю словарь юзернейм:перевод, но и это тоже не помогло, я видел что используют Memory Storage, но я пишу на aiogram3.3 . Видел еще какие то state но про них найти ничего не смог. Молю о помощи, т.к. это будет засчитываться еще как мой индивидуальный проект по информатике, а скоро предзащита. Так что же я все таки хочу:
желательно объяснение с кодом и ссылкой на ресурс, если вы что то обновили в коде(добавили то, чего там нет), если вам лень писать код, я все понимаю, просто скажите в какую сторону мне копать, заранее спасибо! Вот код(знаю что там много непонятного, но это просто наметки и мои заметки, я не думал что столкнусь с проблемами поэтому писал код нелаконично и оставил много ненужного, уберу это все когда закончу):

```
from aiogram import F
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.utils.formatting import Text, Bold
from lists_words import *
# import logging
import random

# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(bot_token, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher()

ru_words = [i[1:] for i in all_words]
en_words = [i[0] for i in all_words]
lang = 'en'
sessions = {}


@dp.message(F.text, Command('start'))
async def start_command(message: types.Message, bot: Bot):
    builder_inline = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder_reply = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder_reply.add(types.KeyboardButton(text='Отправка русского слова'))
    builder_reply.add(types.KeyboardButton(text='Отправка английского слова'))
    content = Text(
        'Привет, ',
        Bold(message.from_user.full_name),
        '!'
    )
    user_id = "тут мой юзер айди"
    chat_info = await bot.get_chat(user_id)
    if not chat_info.has_private_forwards:
        builder_inline.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Связаться с разработчиком',
            url=f'мой телеграм'
        )
        )

    await message.answer(
        **content.as_kwargs(),
        reply_markup=builder_reply.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)

    )
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer(
        'Если у вас есть вопросы, то можно',
        reply_markup=builder_inline.as_markup()
    )


@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'отправка русского слова')
async def send_ru(message: types.Message):
    global rand_word_index
    global lang
    rand_word_index = random.randint(0, len(ru_words) - 1)
    session_id = message.from_user.username
    word1 = en_words[rand_word_index]
    word2 = ', '.join(ru_words[rand_word_index])
    sessions[session_id] = word1
    print('Дикт сессионс', sessions)
    lang = 'ru'
    print('Бот пишет ' + message.from_user.full_name + ': ' + word2)
    await message.answer(f'{word2}')


@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'отправка английского слова')
async def send_ru(message: types.Message):
    global rand_word_index
    global lang
    rand_word_index = random.randint(0, len(ru_words) - 1)
    word1 = ', '.join(ru_words[rand_word_index])
    word2 = en_words[rand_word_index]
    session_id = message.from_user.username
    sessions[session_id] = word1
    print('Дикт сессионс:', sessions)
    lang = 'en'
    print('Бот пишет ' + message.from_user.full_name + ': ' + word2)
    await message.answer(f'{word2}')


@dp.message(F.text)
async def send_translate(message: types.Message):
    global rand_word_index
    global lang
    session_id = message.from_user.username
    id = message.from_user.id
    if lang == 'ru':
        if sessions[session_id].find(message.text.lower()) != -1:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=id,
                                   text='✅Верно!'
                                   )
        else:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=id,
                                   text='❌Ответ неверный. Правильный ответ: ' + en_words[rand_word_index]
                                   )

    elif lang == 'en':
        if sessions[session_id].find(message.text.lower()) != -1:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=id,
                                   text='✅Верно!')
        else:
            await bot.send_message(
                chat_id=id,
                text='❌Ответ неверный. Правильный ответ: ' + ', '.join(ru_words[rand_word_index])
            )
    print(message.from_user.first_name + ' отвечает: ' + message.text)


async def main():
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Вот кусок файла all_words:

```
all_words = [['hello', 'привет', 'здравствуйте'], ['an admission', 'вход', 'входная палата'],
             ['abandoned', 'заброшенный', 'покинутый'],
             ['acceptable', 'приемлемый', 'допустимый'], ['to act', 'действовать'],
             ['an actor', 'актер', 'актёр'], ['an actress', 'актриса'],
             ['affection', 'привязанность'], ['after all', 'в конце концов', 'после всего'],
             ['to allow', 'разрешать', 'позволять'], ['ancient cultures', 'древние культуры'],
             ['an art', 'искусство'], ['an artist', 'художник', 'артист'], ['awful', 'ужасный'],
             ['biopic', 'биографический фильм'],
             ['black and white films', 'черно белые фильмы', 'чёрно белые фильмы'],
             ['brilliant', 'блестящий', 'сверкающий'], ['a building', 'здание', 'постройка'],
             ['a cartoon', 'мультфильм'], ['a catastrophe', 'катастрофа'],
             ['celebrity', 'знаменитость', 'знаменитый человек'], ['channel', 'канал'],
             ['a character', 'характер', 'образ', 'персонаж'], ['a main character', 'главный персонаж'],
             ['a chewing gum', 'жевательная резинка'], ['a choir', 'хор'], ['a cinema', 'кинотеатр']
             ['classic', 'классический'], ['a collection of poetry', 'сборник поэзии'], ['comedy', 'комедия']]

bot_toke = 'мой токен'
```

Comment: Лучшим вариантом является база данных, но также можно(нужно) воспользоваться fsm https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример использования [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html)

```
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State


class SetWord(StatesGroup):
    word = State() # создали класс с состоянием


@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def start_command(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(SetWord.word) # записываем что скажет пользователь
    await message.answer("Привет, как переводится слово cat?")


@dp.message(SetWord.word)
async def check_word(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(word=message.text) # записываем в класс
    data = await state.get_data() # достаем из класса
    await state.clear() # очищаем класс
    if data["word"] == "кот":
        await message.answer("верно")
    else:
        await message.answer("неверно")
```

Comment: не помогло, думаю что дело в генерации рандомного слова, что rand_word_index в моем коде постоянно изменяется, как мне это исправить, капец, вообще не понимаю

Comment: Не используйте глобальные переменные, с ними бот работает некорректно. Я полностью переписал ваш код, но я не знаю в каком виде у вас поступают данные в `all_words`, если вы скинете кусок этого файла, я смогу уточнить ответ, пока что мой код на словаре: https://pastebin.com/XjKp9wKx

Comment: Но лучше все-таки переписать данные на словарь, если такое возможно

Comment: я изменил вопрос, добавил туда содержимое all_words, я делал со словарями, но меня это не устроило, т.к. больше одного перевода не поддерживалось, сейчас я решил все таки сделать базу данных, все запрограммировал на sqlite3, и все работало через раз, я не понимал что не так, решил нажать кнопку одновременно и вот, переводы полностью путались вообще непонятным образом

Comment: спасибо вам за то что помогаете мне

Comment: АЙЙЙЙЙ, КАПЕЦ Я ГЛУПЫЙ, можно же сделать:     "английкое_слово":"русское_слово1, русское_слово2", я подумал что словарь только одно значение, но я  не подумал что все слова можно сделать в одном значении, капец, придется переписывать 500+ слов..., кстати, ваш код на пейстбине работает отлично, но там приходится каждый раз нажимать старт для того чтобы можно было выбрать язык, можно ли как то обойтись без этого? спасибо вам

Comment: В вашем коде нашел такую строку: rand_word_en, rand_word_ru = random.choice(list(all_words.items())), по сути она превращает то что у вас с словаре в то, что получается у меня во вложенных списках, только там кортежи. но я думаю сути это не меняет, все таки можно оставить списки, или все таки лучше переписать, мне не лень, просто если будет работать одинаково, то не вижу смысла

Comment: Нет, тогда не принципиально, пусть в кортежах будет

Comment: Что бы постоянно не нажимать на start я бы сделал так: https://pastebin.com/FQ6Nhg1W

Comment: все, работает, но я решил подправить для своих списков, и поменял ваше random.choice(list(all_words.items())) на rand_word_en, *rand_word_ru = random.choice(all_words), потом сделал такую проверку, if data["diff_word"].lower().find(data["word"].lower()) != -1: await message.answer("Верно"), но теперь если я ввожу даже часть слова, оно пишет верно, и это логично, сейчас думаю сделать через for, но тоже не особо получается, потому что если я пишу так:    for i in data['diff_word']:
        if i.lower() == data['word'].lower():
            await message.answer('Верно')
Тогда неверно будет

Comment: писаться несколько раз, https://pastebin.com/Xe5x3aAp

Comment: Я предлагаю не мучатся и перевести в словарь, в пастебине оставил маленькую функцию по переводу из списка в словарь, на всякий случай. Изучите код, теперь вы можете делать вариации не только к английскому слову, но и к русскому https://pastebin.com/bui99wQK

Comment: капец, ты гений, спасибо тебе огромное, только я воспользовался твоей командой которая закомментирована была, там оно преобразовало, но получалось не ('hello',):['привет','здравствуйте'], а 'hello':['привет', 'здравствуйте'], я исправил это вот так: {tuple([key]): value for key, value in all_words.items()}, еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А, да, я просто функцию сделал до tuple, удачи в защите